# How To resolve "NameError: name 'export_graphviz' is not defined"

Tags: jupyter-notebook, graphviz

export_graphviz is not defined error!!

```
Used the following codes in Jupyrer notebook Python 3.x

`def show_tree (tree, features, path):
        f = io.StringIO()
        export_graphviz(tree, out_file = f, feature_names=features )
        pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(f.getvalue()).write_png(path)
        img = misc.imread(path)
        plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=[20,20]
        plt.imshow(img)
```

show_tree(dt,features,'dc_tree.png')
    `

Got the following error when calling the function show_tree

```
        `NameError Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-21-96002279767f> in <module>()
    ----> 1 show_tree(dt,features,'dc_tree.png')

    `<ipython-input-20-f73dae020a9a> in show_tree(tree, features, path)
          4 def show_tree (tree, features, path):
          5     f = io.StringIO()
    ----> 6     export_graphviz(tree, out_file = f, feature_names=features )
          7     pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(f.getvalue()).write_png(path)
          8     img = misc.imread(path)`
```

NameError: name 'export_graphviz' is not defined

Comment: the error means that there is no definition of the function `export_graphviz` in the current closure

Answer (score 0):

To use the export_graphviz exporter you need to import it from sklearn.tree.

Try

`from sklearn import tree`

([see example at the bottom of this page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html#sklearn.tree.export_graphviz))

or

`from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz`